# String! to String Error?

Tags: ios, string

On this line: `self.file.fileName = (alert.textFields[0] as! UITextField).text`, I get an error saying that "Cannot Assign a Value of Type String! to a Value of Type String". I have tried casting String! to String, but then I got the error "Cannot Assign a Value of Type String to a Value of Type String". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a cool way to do it:

```
let fileNameNew = (alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField).text
file.fileName = "\(fileNameNew)"
```

Just copy the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
if let text: String = (alert.textFields[0] as! UITextField).text as? String {
    self.file.fileName = text
}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error "String! is not convertible to String".

Comment: my bad i forgot the ? with the `as`. Updated my answer

Comment: Got error: Could not find an overload for subscript that accepts the supplied arguments.